# Why are the moderators closing posts?

Tags: discussion

It seems anything argumentative of Unity is being closed. Great work on community support!!! You all know Unity is trash. It was a bad Idea. Now you should let the community fix the problem and the best way to do this is let us complain. Here are a few things. Give me my task bar and main menu back. What else is wrong with Unity?

Comment: If you feel so pasionate about something that you find yourself compelled to argue about it on the internet I advise you either [discuss it on the forums](http://ubuntuforums.com), [chat with people in IRC](http://www.ubuntu.com/support/community/chat), or [do something about it](http://launchpad.net/unity). Your opinions are just that - opinions. Subjective. [Not welcome here](http://askubuntu.com/faq#dontask).

Answer (score 17):

The site is for questions that can be answered. Not gripes (or praise) about the new releases.

If you have an issue that can be asked in a question format (that isn't super-subjective, rhetorical, etc -- eg a question that can have "one best answer"), we welcome it. Otherwise it's our job to make sure people who need help get it. Closing random discussions is part of that.

Coincidentally, if you don't like Unity, you can select Classic Ubuntu from the login screen which will give you a similar experience to Ubuntu 10.10.

**Edit** I should go on to clarify that *any* topic (not just Unity) is a candidate for closure if it can't be sensibly answered. This is by no means a conspiracy to protect Unity or to shield its developers from criticism.

Comment: +1 for condemning this behavior **and** suggesting a solution in one answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Moderators close posts that are not questions, but rather inflammatory remarks or statements that demand subjective replies. Asking "Why does X suck" isn't a question that is appropriate for this site, and does not promote community support. Asking "I don't like X, what can I do to make X more usable/enjoyable/better" or "I don't like X, what are my alternatives?" are better ways to get a response.

Comment: What's wrong with X? I like X! Best graphical display server I've ever used.

Comment: @Oli: X ate my kitten!

Comment: You know what, I totally didn't notice the relation there! Oh well, I was tired. I would change it, but then your comment would make no sense :P

Comment: @Oli clearly you have not used wayland .

Answer (score 3):

This site is for questions and answers - not for arguments.  Suggest ubuntuforums.org and the community-cafe forum for such posts.

Answer (score 2):

*Unity plays nicely with my dog, which is dead. Same way how your question plays nicely with my answer, which is not an answer.*

Get the point I'm making?
"Questions" (rants) like this lead no where constructive, so we (the community) close them to avoid such problems as arguments, trolling, and flame wars. *(No; moderators are not fire fighters).*